# How to get local path of file in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, filepath, flutter-web

I'm using file_picker which give the path to the file in mobile, but in web the path is always null.

I read somewhere you can get the bytes of the file, but I couldn't understand how this it's done.

Right now I am trying to pick a video and showed on my web page with video_player, this method accepts a File.

So, is it possible to get the path of my video somehow and transformed to File?

Comment: Have you tried ```FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.video)```?

Comment: @RaineDaleHolgado yeah, but the path to local files is still null

Comment: did you solve it?